# Executing a python script on multpile nodes by using ssh command in BASH

Tags: python, bash, shell, ssh

keygen etc. so I can just ssh remotehost w/o using password, shell =BASH
I am using a for loop to ssh over multiple nodes (remote host) and wish to execute a script but it dosent seem to work

```
    for i in {1..10};
    do 
    ssh -f node$i "python script.py $i"   
    done
```

the terminal script hangs up and nothing happens
Also I can manually ssh and use python. The PYTHONPATH etc are configured for enodes.

There was cshell on nodes, so i used .cshrc wit exec /bin/bash which atleast when i log manually gives me bash shell, so problem doesent seem to be there.
I

Comment: I does not hang up, just goes background (`-f` option).

Comment: i have used ssh node$i nohup  " python script.py $i"; it did not work  as well. My python scripts makes a dir and writes as well, is this a problem.

Comment: Take a look at fabfile.org

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping python script in a shell script, you should probably have a python script that connects to all the remote hosts via ssh and executes stuff.

[Paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/) is a very good framework for this kind of use-case. It will be much easier to maintain your script this was in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Use -o BatchMode=yes
and maybe you need to force allocate pseudo-tty and -n to prevent reading from stdin